# Cakephp: How to re-use code in different controller

Tags: cakephp

I have some controller, It use same code idea, only different when call model

ex:

- In bookscontroller:

  *`public function abc(){  $this->Book->find(....);  }`*
- In categoriescontroller:

  *`public function abc(){ $this->Category->find(....); }`*

I think it too waste. So, please teach me how to write only one function, but it can call in any controller and load same model.

Thank a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

If you think you need to DRY (dont repeat yourself) that, use components.
They can share code between controllers.

In your case you might also want to look into the [crud plugin](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud) which takes basic CRUD one step further.

Answer (score 0):

> I think it too waste. So, please teach me how to write only one
>   function, but it can call in any controller and load same model.

You answered half of your question already: **DON'T** put the code in a controller. Everything related to data manipulating and fetching should go into a model, not a controller.

Assuming you are in your books controller and book belongs to category you can simply call from there:

```
$this->set('someCategoryData', $this->Book->Category->yourCustomMethod());
$this->set('categories', $this->Book->Category->find('list'));
```

Need a book from the categories controller?

```
$this->set('book', $this->Category->Book->view($bookId));
```

You should fetch the data through the associations and have model methods for your data retrival and manipulation tasks.

A component that calls 1000 models with the logic inside the component is clearly the wrong approach. [Read about SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: Thank burzum :), I just newbie, I got it